# Solve basic system of equations with two unknowns. Why solution doesn't exists?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, numerical-linear-algebra, wolfram-alpha

**The following equation has no solution, but I'm not sure why exactly:**
$7  = 3x_1 + 5x_2 \\
13 = (1 - x_1)3 + (1 - x_2)5 + 21$

**Code** for [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/)

```
7  = 3*x_1 + 5*x_2
13 = (1 - x_1) * 3 + (1 - x_2) * 5 + 21
```

It seems there are two unknowns and two equations, so this seems like something which should be solvable?

I appreciate that it isn't, but I'm not sure how to explain to myself why it isn't solvable. I just remember that if there were $n$ equations and $\leq n$ unknowns, we were able to solve the system .

[image]

Comment: The first equation is $x_2 = ( - 3x_1 + 7)/5$. Substituting into the second we obtaion $0=9$. This has a solution if and only if $3=0$. In general, two linear equations need not have a solution: consider, say, the system of equations $x_1+2x_2=0$ and $x_1+2x_2=1$.

Comment: This forms the basic of **Pair of Linear Equations in Two Variables**. Try going through [this](https://ncert.nic.in/textbook/pdf/jemh103.pdf) PDF, and more particularly Page-$9$ of PDF.

Comment: If one adds two equations given, one can easily get $7+13=3+5+21$ which is not true. Then equations are contradictory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you rewrite your system as a linear equation, you end up with a singular matrix of rank 1. The column space (image space) of a rank 1 matrix does not span $\mathbb{R}^2$ (it is one-dimensional), so almost every right hand side (or left hand side in your case) will result in a system without a solution.

Put differently: The two equations on your right hand side are not linearly independent (they are the same up to linear transformations), but your left hand side does not reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the equations are nonsensical, since expanding out the second one yields
$ \sout{5x_2 = - 3x_1}$
which gives $7 = 0$ when substituted back into the first equation.
The equations are inconsistent with/incongruent to each other.

Sorry, strike that. Missed a minus sign. But 16 still does not equal 7 so the comment holds.